# What is "Toby the Vampire Slayer" and why can't I find it?

Tags: story-identification, vampire, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

I found a reference on IMDB to an animated show called "[Toby the Vampire Slayer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3149238/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt)". Evidently it only ran for 2 years, had a micro-budget and no decent actors but that's no good reason for it to be quite so *invisible*.

So why can't I find it? What is it and where can I watch it, or even a trailer?

Comment: Your IMDB link indicates it is still an ongoing series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright. Here is the first episode of the so called "Toby the Vampire Slayer."

*The comments of the video have a user named iHunter, turns out this is Hunter Husnay.*

Here is the YouTube channel of the "star" of the series [Hunter Husnay](https://www.youtube.com/user/wildwildgirls100/videos).

I know it is him because all of his IMDB credits for things like STAB 8 and STAB 9 are also linked here as his videos.

**Conclusion: He put all his home movies and videos / School of heARTS projects on IMDB as his acting, writing, and directing credits, along with his friends.**

Comment: [This page](http://hunterhusnay.weebly.com/bio.html) on Hunter Husnay's site has some background, apparently it was made with help from someone named Michael J. Widger who he met at "School of the heARTS", and [Michael J. Widger's facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/michael.d.widger) mentions in [this post](http://www.facebook.com/michael.d.widger/posts/575185252500885) that this is an afterschool program Michael runs.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I just changed my YouTube link to link to DooWittle's video, which is the School of heARTS version.

Comment: Wow. This is sooooo bad it's almost good.

Comment: @Richard It's better than bad, it's good!